# How to handle multiple forms with dynamic radio buttons on same page using python and html?

Tags: html, python-3.x

Good Day!

I'm having a unique problem where I have to create a HTML page which has 3 forms, in which the radio buttons are generated dynamically based on the input of the previous form. I'm using Python 3.6 and HTML.

Parts of my code:

from the app:

```
selection1 = sorted(list(Some_Table['var1'].unique()))
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.form['submit1']:
        selection2 = sorted(list(pandas.DataFrame(Some_Table[Some_Table['var1'] == request.form['Header1']])['var2'].unique()))
        return render_template('view.html', selection2 = selection2, selection1=selection1)
        if request.form['submit2']:
            selection3 = sorted(list(pandas.DataFrame(Some_Table[Some_Table['var2'] == request.form['Header2']])['var3'].unique()))
            return render_template('view.html', selection3 = selection3, selection2 = selection2, selection1=selection1)
return render_template('view.html', selection1=selection1)
```

from the html script:

```html
<div2>
<form action="" method="post">
<p> {% for c1 in selection1 %}
<input type="radio" name="Header1" value={{c1}}> {{c1}} </input><br>
{% endfor %} </p>
<p> <input type=submit name=submit1 value="Show Table1"> </p>
</form>
</div2>

<div2 style="margin-top: 250px; ">
<form action="" method="post">
<p> {% for c2 in selection2 %}
<input type="radio" name="Header2" value={{c2}}> {{c2}} </input><br>
{% endfor %} </p>
<p> <input type=submit name=submit2 value="Show Table2"> </p>
</form>
</div2>

<div2 style="margin-top: 500px; ">
<form action="" method="post">
<p> {% for c3 in selection3 %}
<input type="radio" name="Header3" value={{c3}}> {{c3}} </input><br>
{% endfor %} </p>
<p> <input type=submit name=submit3 value="Show Table3"> </p>
</form>
</div2>
```

Comment: Are you using any web frame work?for example django ? if yes then do mention

Comment: Yes Sir, I'm using Flask as web frame work.

Comment: will the values of these three generated radio buttons will come from database ? or we can determine it on client side ?

Comment: We can determine the values of the three generated radio buttons on the client side.

Comment: Then you should use jquery to handle this..

Comment: I'm very new to HTML and Web Frame works, Can you please point me on the right direction to handle this? It would be very helpful if you can post an example code of handling this.

Comment: try this example by adding dumy values first in your second form.. upon selection of first... then replace that dummy values logic with your desired one

Answer (score 0):

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
var radioBtn = $('<input type="radio" name="rbtnCount" />');
radioBtn.appendTo('#target');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="target"></form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and time, I will revert if it had worked and thank you once again for your help!

Comment: @NikhileshRoy  No problem .. you are welcome.. can you please accept it as answer?

Comment: Yes sir, I surely will !  I think there is a problem in the way my python code is structured, but I'm unable to identify where! Can you also have a look at it and revert if there is any change to be made?

Comment: @NikhileshRoy yes sure, you cannot submit two forms at once without using jquery, if you want to submit separately then don't use "submit2" code inside "submit1 " if